# Google Cloud + Node + Postgres connection string

Tags: node.js, postgresql, google-cloud-platform

I'm new to Google Cloud, coming over from Heroku. Also newish to Postgres and Node, so forgive the noob question.

With Heroku, I used the following to connect my app to my database:

```
var pg = require('pg');
pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client) {
//...
});
```

Is there an equivalent formulation of `process.env.DATABASE_URL` on Google's app engine?

Using `process.env.DATABASE_URL` gave me an `ECONNREFUSED` error, so I tried replacing it with various iterations of the 'protocol://name:pass@host:port/db' construction (specifically, using both 'tcp' and 'postgres'; 'localhost' and explicit address), but this only gives the following error:

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.196.122.108:5432
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:874:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:897:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1063:14)
```

I set up my database according to [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/setup-postgres).

What am I missing here?

Comment: you should be able to set env variables in the app.yaml [see](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml) concerning connectivity, are you trying to connect remotely? If so, have you opened the req. ports/made firewall changes?

Comment: Ah! Great tip on the app.yaml file—thanks. I'm trying to connect from my app (on Google's servers) so there should be no firewall issues, no? I've also tried using both external and internal IPs for my database instance…the former gives the time out error while the latter fails to even deploy properly.

Comment: if your app is on the same server as the pg db, then there should not be any issues.  However, if your app is on server1 and your db is on server2, even if both are google servers, you'll need to make some modifications. From the tutorial you reference-->"By default, Postgres doesn't allow remote connections"

Comment: Bingo! App and database were on different Google servers. I whitelisted the IPs for my app's VM instances in the database config and firewall and—off to the races! Thanks again @scottjustin5000

Comment: nice! glad i could help!

Comment: @BenjaminRedd what was the pg.connect string did you end up using, I am having same issue migrating from Heroku Postgres